# Is it appropriate to divide a rate evenly among individual units?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working with a rate of effort on a project. Since I think my question would apply to any type of rate, let's use something like miles per hour (mph) for simplicity's sake. Let's say I have a group of four cars with an average speed of 80 mph; I don't know what each car's distance or time is so I must distribute evenly among all four cars. Therefore, I say each car traveled 20 miles in 0.25 hours. I don't know the right words, but to me, distance and time are like single units, so they can be divided in this way. This results in EACH car going an average speed of 80 mph, as well as the whole group going an average speed of 80 mph. Again, this makes sense to me because a rate shouldn't be divided among parts to add up to a whole (at least, I think).

Here's the question: someone told me that the way I should be attributing the rate to each car is to divide distance as I have done, but leave the denominator (time) the same, resulting in each car traveling 20 miles in one hour, such that each car has traveled at an average speed of 20 mph. Then to get the total speed of the group, you add the rate of speed of each car. According to this person, if you want the rate PER CAR, you have to leave per car in the denominator -- in other words, if you divide the distance per car and the time per car, then your average speed does not end up being the speed per car because you're canceling this out (which is what I have above).

I'm not sure if we are actually trying to answer two different questions here? I feel like I *almost* understand what the other person is trying to say, but I just don't quite get it. I am hoping someone here who understands this more intuitively than I do might be able to break it down for me. Thanks for any help!

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without more information about your specific application: I'd say these are both entirely valid operations, but they don't necessarily apply to the same problems, so some details on your application would be appreciated.

Comment: it may be simpler to go from individual car speeds to average speed rather than "dividing" the average speed amongst the four cars. to get average speed from individual speeds, you would want to weight individual speeds by the distances covered by each car.

Comment: @RahulMadhavan Part of the issue is that I only have the group rate and the number of units -- no other information to do such weighting. For my purposes, it is sufficient to assume all units are weighted evenly. My question is whether the individual rate is equal to the group rate or to the group rate divided by the number of units.

Comment: @StephenDonovan I have group rates where the group is composed of anywhere from 1 to 10 units. The sampling unit in this case was the group. For my purposes, though, I need the data on the scale of the individual units. It is okay to not have the information to weight each individual unit. I want to know how to apply the information I have to get the rate per unit.

Comment: I thought it might be easier to describe using something like miles per hour per car but maybe it is better to just give the units I am using. I have fish caught and # of anglers per trip. Effort equals # fish caught/# anglers. Each trip visited a certain number of spatial units (equally sized). So for example, if there is a trip with 8 fish caught and 4 anglers, the effort rate is 2. Now let's say we visited 4 spatial units -- is the effort per spatial unit also 2? Or is it 0.5? Apologies if I made it more confusing by not just  leading with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let total distance travelled = $d$. Then the individual distances travelled are $d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4$ such that $d=d_1+d_2+d_3+d_4$. Let $t$ be the total time taken, and $t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4$ be the individual times. Finally, let the rates (velocities in this case) be $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$, with the group rate (or in this case average velocity) being $v$.

Now we have
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
v_1 = \frac{d_1}{t_1} &v_2 = \frac{d_2}{t_2}&v_3 = \frac{d_3}{t_3} &v_4= \frac{d_4}{t_4}\\
d_1 = v_1t_1 &d_2 = v_2t_2 &d_3 = v_3t_3 &d_4= v_4t_4\\
\hline
\end{array}

Then
\begin{align*}
v&=\frac{d}{t}\\&= \frac{d_1+d_2+d_3+d_4}{t_1+t_2+t_3+t_4}\\&= \frac{v_1t_1+v_2t_2 +v_3t_3 +v_4t_4}{t_1+t_2+t_3+t_4}
\end{align*}

**Assumption 1:** all units are weighted equally. Say $t_1=t_2=t_3=t_4 = k$. Then we have

\begin{align*}
v&= \frac{v_1k+v_2k +v_3k +v_4k}{4k}\\
&= \frac{v_1+v_2 +v_3 +v_4}{4}\\
\end{align*}
**Assumption 2:** all rates are the same. Say $v_1=v_2=v_3=v_4 = u$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
v&= \frac{v_1+v_2 +v_3 +v_4}{4}\\
&= \frac{u+u +u +u}{4}\\
&=u
\end{align*}
**Conclusion:** So group rate $v$ is equal to individual rate $u$ under the given assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for this breakdown. Is there a situation where the alternative I give in my question would be appropriate (NOT dividing the denominator by the number of individuals in the group)?

Comment: yes it would be appropriate when you are dividing say the distance. then group distance $d = d_1+d_2+d_3+d_4$